# YouTube Subscriptions List Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping, scrapinghub

I want to scrap my YouTube subscriptions list into one csv file. I typed this code (but I didn't finish coding yet):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels'
source = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

I found this error:

> File "/Users/hendy/YouTube subscriptions scraping.py", line 7, in
>
> soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')   File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/bs4/**init**.py",
> line 312, in **init**
> elif len(markup) <= 256 and ( TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What happens?

You using the whole `response` object and push it to `BeautifulSoup` what would not work.

#### How to fix?

To generate a `BeautifulSoup` object use the `content` or `text` of your response:

```
BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers ={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://www.youtube.com/feed/channels'
source = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, 'lxml')
```